# How do I theme the title of a block in a view

Tags: view, drupal-7

I am using views and I have created a block. I need to add a span to Newest members.

I tried using the theme tpl files given by views. The top most file is views-view.tpl.php, I added a class to the first div "vishaltest" however u can see it starts a bit lower than what I want. how can I override this section

```
<div class="block-title">Newest members</div>
```

the code:

```
<section id="block-views-5a3590205379433adabbd042516161b0" class="block block-views clearfix">

<div class="block-title">Newest members</div>

<div class="view view-recently-added-updated-profiles view-id-recently_added_updated_profiles     view-display-id-newest_member view-dom-id-e8042a917bbe79ecf65705f5c8bda2a3 vishaltest">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have more chance to access the block title through `block--views-view.tpl.php` using `$block->subject` variable.